# No response from serial communication write command

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a serial port that I want to communicate with using node js. Here is the dump of successful communication interaction. 
this is my spec (async serial protocol) 
[spec doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDzzl.png)

(COM1 in windows)
[successful serial port communication screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY2nc.png)

However when I use nodejs to replicate that interaction, I don't get any response from the port. (/dev/tty.usbserial-14420 in macOS)

```
var serialport = require("serialport"); 

const port = "/dev/tty.usbserial-14420";

const ACK = 0x06;
const NAK = 0x15;
const ENQ = 0x05;
const EOT = 0x04;
const STX = 0xF2;
const ETX   = 0x03;
const CMT = "C";


let f3 = new serialport(port, {
  baudRate: 9600
})

var Readline = serialport.parsers.Readline; // make instance of Readline parser
var parser = new Readline(); // make a new parser to read ASCII lines
f3.pipe(parser); // pipe the serial stream to the parser

f3.on('open', () => {
    console.log('port open');
    f3.write(makeMessage1());
    f3.write(makeMessage0());
    f3.write(makeMessage2());
});

parser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("data received "+data);
});

f3.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('error: ' + error);
})

function makeMessage0() {
  return new Buffer.from('05');
}

function makeMessage1() {
  return new Buffer.from('f2 00 00 03 43 30 33 03 b2');
}


function makeMessage2() {
  return new Buffer.from('f2 00 00 03 43 32 03 ba');
}
```

output:

```
port open
```

Comment: I don't know the language you're using, but obviously the async protocol is binary (i.e. not text), whereas it seems that you're sending a text string of alphanumeric characters.   Not that it really matters, but makeMessage2 doesn't have enough "bytes" to form a minimal message of at least nine bytes (i.e. it's supposed to be the same length as msg1 yet is shorter).

Comment: @sawdust ah that makes sense, so my next step is figuring out how to reverse engineer what is in the binary

Comment: *"what is in the binary"* -- Huh??!!  Look at your screenshot of *"successful serial port communication"*.  Notice that the left side has a hex representation of the binary data bytes that are written.  Also note that to the right there is an ASCII translation of those bytes.  IOW you already have the binary values of (some) messages (in hex representation).  Your *"next step"* should be figuring-out/learning how to construct a binary message buffer from hex values.

Comment: BTW text strings have an intrinsic length, whereas an array of bytes has to be declared/allocated with a specific size, and your program has to explicitly keep track of the quantity of data in that array (i.e. because there is no delimiter character byte).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is node, I can see two major issues with your code as written:

- You should not have spaces between the hex values in the first parameter of `Buffer.from`
- You should provide a second parameter of "hex" to Buffer.from: `Buffer.from('f200000343303303b2', 'hex');`